# Referencing a 2d array in a class function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, dynamic-allocation

Can't access a 2D array that I created in the constructor in the printMatrix class function. When I call the function in main with a simple cout << "test"; it will print that. If I try to print the values of matrixArray[][] it prints nothing and quits the program. Am I not referencing the 2d array correctly?

```
class matrix
{
    int **matrixArray;

public:
    int matrixSize = 0;
    matrix(int matrixSize);
    void printMatrix();
    void makeMagicSquare();
};
matrix::matrix(int const matrixSize)
{
    this->matrixSize = matrixSize ;


    int** matrixArray = new int*[matrixSize];
        for(int i = 0; i<matrixSize; i++){
           matrixArray[i] = new int[matrixSize];
        }


    for(int row = 0; row < matrixSize ;row++)
            {
                for(int col = 0; col < matrixSize; col++)
                {
                    matrixArray[row][col] =0;
                    cout << matrixArray[row][col] << "  ";
                }//End for Col
                cout << endl;
            }//End for Row

}
//printMatrix Function 
void matrix::printMatrix(){

for(int row = 0; row < matrixSize;row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < matrixSize; col++)
            {
                cout << "test" << "  ";
                //Not able to print  from print function
                cout << matrixArray[row][col] << endl;
            }// end col
            cout << endl;
        }//end row

}
```

Comment: You really should store the matrix in a one dimensional vector.

Comment: will somebody smack you if you use `vector<vector<int> >` instead?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Only someone who cares a lot about cache locality. 1D vectors are better.

Comment: @vsoftco right about that. I did not see your comment :) I was talking about `int **` versus `vector<vector>` and all the memory problems it solves. I agree that 1D vectors are better, but you have to wrap them into an object or you constantly shoot yourself in the foot with index computations.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes I knew you were relating to `int**` :) Right about the indexing, but if you don't want to complicate (using a proxy class) one can re-define `operator()(size_t, size_t)` for indexing.

Comment: Yeah the OP is not sure about how to do what he wants, let's bomb him with the vector VS array, 1D vs 2D stuff..One step at a time guys! :)

Comment: don't forget to use SSE2 for vectorized complex multiplications :)

Comment: isn't there some templates sources like Template Numerical Toolkit to define vectors & matrices without coding something that crashes?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) is a VERY good/fast templated C++ matrix library.

Answer (score 4):

How could you?

```
int** matrixArray = new int*[matrixSize];
```

is a **local variable** inside the constructor, thus `matrixArray` is only visible inside the constructor.

Use the data member instead and you will be fine, and since you already have defined that member, you should just do this:

```
matrixArray = new int*[matrixSize];
```

Don't forget to delete your memory in the destructor! ;)

Comment: Actually OP just has to remove `int**`. Good catch!

Comment: Thanks @vsoftco, I updated my answer though to make it super-clear to everyone! ;)

Comment: and don't forget to create a copy constructor and an assignment operator that does not just copy the pointer value but duplicates the data, without memory leaks. Good luck, it's not that easy.

Comment: another trick: name your class members differently: `m_matrix`, `_matrix`  to avoid mixups like this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You should really avoid names starting with a leading underscore.  In certain cases using them is UB so it is just best to avoid the situation entirely.

Comment: Oh @NathanOliver has a point here, better not use the leading underscore, he is right!

Comment: Right! I dropped them in favour of `m_matrix` anyway. Somebody must have told me that before :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Here are the rules: http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/3093378. So `_identifier` (with lower case `i`) should be fine, as long as it's not in the global namespace. I used this convention and now I was super worried that I'd need to refactor...

Comment: of course! if defined as a C-like symbol it would be a nightmare to the linker. I was using Visual C++ 98 at the time, so I had worse worries :)

Comment: Thanks for the help and all the tips.

Comment: @TimBotelho you are welcomed. Is there a reason for not accepting my answer? :/

Answer (score 1):

You've made a very common mistake, failing to distinguish between locally scoped variables/parameters and member variables.

```
int** matrixArray = new int*[matrixSize];
```

Because this expression starts with a type, it is a *declaration* of a new, local variable, which is "hiding" the class member (you would have to use `this->matrixArray` to access it, and it would not be initialized). Your compiler *should* be giving you a "shadow variable" warning.

A common practice is to give member variables a distinguisher: some people prefix them with "m_", some put a trailing "_", so your code would become:

```
class matrix
{
    int **matrixArray_ = nullptr;  //1
    int matrixSize_ = 0;  //2

public:
    matrix(int matrixSize);
    ~matrix();  //7
    void printMatrix() const;
    void makeMagicSquare();
    int size() const { return matrixSize_; }  //3
};

matrix::matrix(int const matrixSize)
    : matrixSize_(matrixSize)  //4
{
    matrixArray_ = new int*[matrixSize_];  //5
    for(int i = 0; i<matrixSize_; i++) {
        matrixArray_[i] = new int[matrixSize_] ();  //6
    }
}

matrix::~matrix()  //7
{
    if (!_matrixArray)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize_; ++i) {
        delete [] matrixArray_[i];
    }
    delete [] matrixArray_;
}

void matrix::printMatrix() const
{
    for(int row = 0; row < matrixSize_; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < matrixSize_; col++) {
            cout << "test" << "  ";
            cout << matrixArray_[row][col] << endl;
        }// end col
        cout << endl;
    }//end row
}
```

1: Added '_' suffix and might as well make sure we don't accidentally get garbage here,

2: Added '_' suffix and I made private so it doesn't get tweaked from outside,

3: Added a 'size()' accessor member function,

4: Use initializer list to copy "matrixSize" parameter to "matrixSize_" member,

5: Removed the 'int**' and note we're using 'matrixArray_' - member,

6: The `()` after the `new int[matrixSize_]` tells the compiler to default 
initialize the columns for us (sets them to zero) In modern C++ this would be `{}` instead, but then I'm not sure if you're using a modern C++ compiler and both work.

7: Added a destructor to release the memory used

For similar reasons, I would encourage you to consider making your type names distinct: `class Matrix` or `class matrix_t`.

Comment: Thanks for the point by point critique. I'm trying to learn best practices and this really helped.

Comment: @TimBotelho Glad it helped! It's important to have some understanding of arrays and dynamic memory allocation, but modern C++ saves you a *lot* of the pain these things cause. Be sure to bookmark [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for later reading - but not too late - save yourself a lot of pain :)